# What is the significance of this Spanish speech in Deadpool?

Tags: dialogue, x-men-cinematic-universe, deadpool

What does it mean, or what is the reference about, when *Deadpool* says *"Me gusta cinco"* ("I like five" in Spanish)? When he is counting down his bullets and dancing like Michael Jackson, is he just celebrating?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, Deadpool is just excited about the shot he made with the fifth from last bullet. It's just typical Deadpool randomness.

In the original leaked script, Deadpool celebrated bullet 7 in Spanish instead:

> DEADPOOL: Siete.
>   *Deadpool FIRES AT THE MIRROR. In SLO-MO, the bullet STRIKES the mirror at an OBLIQUE ANGLE and RICOCHETS perfectly INTO the thug who made the reflection.*
>   DEADPOOL: Ha gusta siete.

The scene was rewritten and things moved around some.

Answer (score 1):

It suggests to me a reference to [The Jackson **5**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Jackson_5)..

> **The Jackson 5**, or **Jackson Five** — and **The Jacksons** in later years, is an American popular music group. Formed in 1963 under the name the Jackson Brothers, the founding members were Jackie, Tito, Jermaine, and Marlon. ***Michael*** would join one year later...

Comment: How is this a reference to the Jacksons? Just because the number five? Maybe it's a reference to Fab 5 Freddy then. The Jacksons arnt the only famous five,  and they don't have any song similar to Deadpool signing in this scene.

Comment: @cde How many acts feature 'dancing like Micheal Jackson'?

Comment: If the dance was a Michael dance, maybe a comparison video would help make your case

Comment: Personally, I would not be too surprised to find it is actually both answers in one; everyone involved in the Dead Pool movie seemed to expressly go out of their way (over the top) with randomness, and making everything jam packed with 4th wall breaking double-, triple- or more- entendre's.